# How can i use parallel transactions in neo4j?

Tags: multithreading, transactions, neo4j

I am currently working on an application using Neo4j as an embedded database.

And I wondering how it would be possible to make sure that separate threads use separate transactions. Normally, I would assign database operations to a transaction, but the code examples I found, don't allow for making sure that write operations use separate transactions:

```
try (Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx()) {
    Node node = graphDb.createNode();
    tx.success();
}
```

As graphDB shall be used as a thread-safe singleton, I really don't see, how that shall work... (E.g. for several users creating a shopping list in separate transactions.)

I would be grateful for pointing out where I misunderstand the concept of transactions in Neo4j.

Best regards and many thanks in advance,
Oliver

Comment: See Christophe's answer, transactions are threadbound, so use a ThreadPool and all si good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you posted *will* run in separate transactions if executed by multiple threads, one transaction per thread.

The way this is achieved (and it's quite a common pattern) is storing transaction state against [ThreadLocal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) (read the Javadoc and things will become clear).

Answer (score 0):

**Neo4j Transaction Management**

In order to fully maintain data integrity and ensure good transactional behavior, Neo4j supports the ACID properties:

atomicity: If any part of a transaction fails, the database state is left unchanged.

consistency: Any transaction will leave the database in a consistent state.

isolation: During a transaction, modified data cannot be accessed by other operations.

durability: The DBMS can always recover the results of a committed transaction.

**Specifically:**

-All database operations that access the graph, indexes, or the schema must be performed in a transaction.

Here are the some useful links to understand Neo4j transactions
http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-transactional.html

http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-transactions.html

http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.db.neo4j.user/20442